# specifics of dilated convolutions in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, time-series, cnn

This ones a little esoteric. I'm developing a wave-net inspired model. First time needing dilated convolutions.

My question is which values is the convolution looking at relative to the output position? For example if I have a `Conv1D` with `kernel_size=4`, `dilation_rate=2` and `padding='same'` are the inputs split evenly to both sides so relative positions of input data would be `(-3,-1,1,3)`, or justified to one side giving relative positions like `(-6,-4,-2,0)` or something different? Is there an easy way to control this behavior?